# Relaxed non-negative least squares

Tags: multivariate-analysis, constrained-regression, non-negative-matrix-factorization, constrained-optimization

I am reconstructing a probability vector from data using non-negative least squares:
$$
\sum_\alpha \left(\pi_\alpha - \sum_i W_{\alpha i}p_i\right)^2\rightarrow \min,\\
p_i\geq 0,\sum_i p_i=1
$$
However, I am really interested in a less finely grained probability vector, $w_\nu$, each element of which is a sum of several of $p_i$ (each $p_i$ occurs only once). Formally this could be written as
$$
w_\nu=\sum\Omega_{\nu i}p_i,\\
\Omega_{\nu i}=0\text{ or } 1,\\ \sum_\nu\Omega_{\nu i}=1
$$

Thus, solving the problem for $p_i$ and then summing to get $w_\nu$ might be too stringent an approach. How could one set a problem for calculating $w_\nu$ in less restrictive way?

**Remark:**
$\pi_\alpha$ and $w_\nu$ satisfy
$$
\pi_\alpha \geq 0, \sum_\alpha \pi_\alpha \leq 1,\\
w_\nu \geq 0, \sum_\nu w_\nu=1
$$
(For simplicity one can take $\sum_\alpha \pi_\alpha = 1$, although in practice there are some losses, which result in breaking of the normalization.)

Comment: Your formula's are not very clear. Could you explain/describe them. What are $\pi_a$, $W_{\alpha p}$, and $w_\nu$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sum_i W_{\alpha p}$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus see the updated post.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more. I do not understand what the point is of $w_\nu$. You perform the non-negative least squares problem, and then you compute the $w_\nu$. I must be missing something that turned this into a problem.