# Simplistic linear estimator for a probability vector

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, naive-bayes, blue, blup

I am working on a problem where the unknown probabilities $p_i$ are related to observed rates/frequencies $\pi_\alpha$ as
$$
\pi_\alpha = \sum_iW_{\alpha i}p_i,
$$
where $W_{\alpha i}$ is known (rather sparse) matrix.

I have tried a number of techniques for solving this problem, e.g., using the non-negative least squares (see [my other post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/591326/110833) for more background), but eventually found that the most reliable estimator is
$$
p_i = \sum_{\alpha}\frac{\pi_\alpha W_{\alpha i}}{\sum_j W_{\alpha j}}
$$
This estimator was largely a guess, based on my understanding of the underlying biological problem.

**Question:**
Is this a known estimator? If yes, how can it be arrived to in a principled way? What desirable properties doe sit possess and under which conditions can it be used or fails?

**Background:**
The *naïve* reasoning mentioned above was approximately like this:

- $W_{\alpha i}$ can be viewed as conditional probabilities: $P(\alpha) = P(\alpha | i)P(i)$. From Bayes formula we then have $P(i|\alpha)\propto P(\alpha | i)P(i)\propto W_{\alpha i}$.
- If vector $\pi_\alpha$ has only one non-zero entry, the resulting probability vector should be still normalized, $\sum_i p_i=1$, hence the normalization factor $\sum_jW_{\alpha j}$.
- The estimator has an important property that the elements of the estimated vector are *non-negative*.

---

**Update**
@SextusEmpiricus pointed out that, if in the OLS estimator, $\mathbf{p}=(W^TW)^{-1}W\mathbf{\pi}$, one approximates the inverse matrix by its diagonal elements, we obtain
$$
p_i = \sum_\alpha \frac{W_{i\alpha}\pi_\alpha}{\sum_jW_{i\alpha}^2},$$
which is very similar to the estimator above and should be particularly close to it, if the elements of $W_{\alpha i}$ are close to zeros and ones. While the latter is indeed mostly the case, the estimator with $W_{\alpha j}^2$ gives worse results. This however allows me to ask a more precise question about what I really want to know:

**More precise question:**
Is there (what is) a loss function that results in estimator
$$
p_i = \sum_{\alpha}\frac{\pi_\alpha W_{\alpha i}}{\sum_j W_{\alpha j}}?
$$

Comment: If you have a low corration between the columns of you design matrix $W_{\alpha I}$ then the OLS estimator is $$p = (W^tW)^{-1} W \pi $$ then a$(W^tW)^{-1}$ can be approximated with a diagonal matrix (small covariance terms) and  $$p_i \approx  \sum_{\alpha} \frac{W_{i\alpha}}{(W^tW)_{\alpha \alpha}} \approx \sum_{\alpha}\frac{\pi_\alpha W_{\alpha i}}{\sum_j W_{\alpha j}^2}$$ which has a square factor difference with your formula. But maybe $\sum_j W_{\alpha j}^2 = \sum_j W_{\alpha j}$ in your particular situation or you made a typo?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I did try to reason along these lines, though I approximated $W^tW$ rather than its inverse - so your suggestion is a step forward. Yet I have just checked it works worse than the estimator in the OP - perhaps it has to do with normalization (which is not guaranteed by simple OLS that you used).

Comment: These summation and suffixes can be complicated (I believe I have made som errors in my recent comments). Could you maybe add some example to make it clear what we are talking about and allow us to check whether we are on the same page. Also how do you determine *"a step forward"*. The goal that you wish to optimize is not clear.

Comment: Based on your other question you could have the situation that all $W_{\alpha j}$ are equal to either zero or one such that $W_{\alpha j} = W_{\alpha j}^2$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus most of them are indeed close to 0 or 1, but not all. Ideally $p_i$ should be positive and sum to one. Also, if we assume that $\pi_\alpha$ sum to 1, then also $\sum_\alpha W_{\alpha i} =1$. Another thing is that dimensions for $\alpha$ are greater than for $i$ - so the inverse above is poorly defined. Jot sure what other details might be useful.